# AutoHotKey - Alt+` (backtick) to Shift+Alt+Tab

Tags: autohotkey

I want to remap Left <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> to <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, in other words, make it behave like Mac OS X's backward window cycle.

http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm
This page describes how to map some key combination to AltTab and ShiftAltTab, and the examples

```
 LAlt & j::AltTab
 LAlt & k::ShiftAltTab
```

work fine for me.

However, neither

```
 LAlt & `::ShiftAltTab
```

nor

```
 LAlt & vkC0sc029:: ShiftAltTab
```

works.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe ` is a special character, so you might need to escape it. Something like `` or similar.

Comment: Backtick is a special character only where strings can appear. Left hand side of :: is not.

Answer (score 0):

Try Autohotkey_L ([AutoHotkey download](http://www.autohotkey.com/download/))

That is the version I use and your example worked correctly for me on Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit.

```
LAlt & `::ShiftAltTab
```

Comment: Worked! 
(Actually the reason why it didn't work for me was because I was using a Japanese IME, which eats Alt+` as input method switch. This shortcut of IME seems to be non-cancellable with AHK.)
By the way, when I press Alt+Tab, then without releasing the Alt, press ` more than once, and press Tab again, the window cycler goes backward. Does it happen to you too?

Comment: @edvakf: you should post your answer separately and mark it as `accepted` (using the checkmark) so future folk don't need to dig through the comments to find out what worked for you... Thanks!